# how to generate text boxes based on a string value and add each check box to a panel just like a todo-list

Tags: c#, winforms, controls

What I am trying to do is something like:

```
public void thisDoesNotWork (string n)
{
  string textBoxName = n.Substring(0, 4); // assuming the string cannot be less than 4 charcters
  checkbox textBoxName = new checkbox();
  textBoxName.text = n;
  panel.Controls.Add(textBoxName)
}
```

where the string that was past in becomes the name used to instantiate the object.

My goal here is to create a new instance of a new `CheckBox` every time a different string is passed into the method instead of creating the same instance of the same `CheckBox` multiple times.

With the above method am merely adding the exact same `CheckBox` to the panel multiple time, well at lease I think so. But I need to add a brand new check box and not instances of the same.

I hope you guys understand and i am not making this too confusing than it really is.

```
public thisDoesWork(string n) 
{
  CheckBox b = new CheckBox();
  b.Text = n;
  panel.Controls.Add(b);
}
```

Comment: have you run your (executed) code and what result did ya get? I checked the exact you had provided and once ya fixed the class names etc it seems to be working. Try to use [FlowLyaoutPanel](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9w7ek2f%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to add controls as it would place the new controls without overlapping with any existing ones.

Answer (score 0):

May be this will help you:

```
private const int Step = 10
private int y = 0;

public ThisDoesWork(string n) 
{
  CheckBox checkBox = new CheckBox
    {
        Text = n,
        Top = y,
        Parent = panel1
    };

    y += checkBox.Height + Step; // you can set any rules for the postition of new controls
}
```